# Retrieve latest row for each distinct url_id

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this structure for tables

**Reviews table:**

```
id - grade - url_id
1     2       1
2     4       2
3     5       3
4     3       4
5     4       1
6     5       2
7     2       3
```

**Urls table**

```
id - url
1   www.google.com
2   www.apple.com
3   www.bing.com
```

I want to retrieve latest grade inserted for each url_id and join it with urls table, like this:

```
id - grade - url_id - url
5     4       1       www.google.com
6     5       2       www.apple.com
7     2       3       www.bing.com
```

This was my attempt

```
  SELECT a.id, a.reviews, a.url_id, b.url
     FROM (  
         SELECT id, grade, url_id
         FROM reviews
         ORDER BY id DESC
     ) AS a
  INNER JOIN urls
  ON a.url_id = urls.id
  GROUP BY a.url_id
```

I get this error `"Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause"`

How can I edit the code so that it is valid?

I can't say I understood by searching the net what is the problem, other than disabling `only_full_group_by`

Comment: Your subject says you want the latest 2 rows for each url_id, but your description says you want the latest grade. Can you show what result you want, given your example data?

Comment: I added the tag greatest-n-per-group. This is a common question that has been answered many times on Stack Overflow. Please see if you can find a solution among those answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent version, then you can filter using a `where` clause:

```
select r.*
from reviews r
where r.id = (select max(r2.id) from reviews r2 where r2.url_id = r.url_id);
```

You can join in the url itself, if that is necessary.

Comment: Thank you your time but this will select only one row

Comment: @IvanTopić . . . Why would you think that?  Do you not understand correlated subqueries?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT r.*
FROM reviews r
WHERE r.grade = ( SELECT Max(r2.grade) 
                FROM reviews r2  
                WHERE r2.url_id = r.url_id )
ORDER BY r.url_id
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.